# node.js: process.argv and $ symbol

Tags: node.js, shell, process

It's a small issue but nevertheless.. Did anybody picked that node's **process.argv** removes symbol `$` from the string passed to the shell,

example:

```
mycommand 'mystring: { $exists: true }'
```

outputs:

```
[ 'node',
  '/usr/local/bin/mycommand',
  'mystring: { : true }' ]
```

as you see together with `$` disappeared word `exists`, is it normal behavior?

Comment: Did you try escaping the `$` symbol? That symbol is normally used for variables in BASH (http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-5.html) and PowerShell

Comment: ... so it's the shell that supplies an empty string to the script.

Comment: I bet you're actually using double quotes, not single quotes -- http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Double-Quotes